# How to set a Window size to 0?

Tags: c#, wpf

It seems that I am unable to set the Height Property of a Window element to 0. Is there an explanation for that?

This code does not works, nor does forcing Height to 0 in Code behind works. ActualHeight always returns 14.0 for my machine

```
<Window x:Class="AnimWindow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="0" Width="525" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" Background="YellowGreen" >

</Window>
```

Hint appreciated.

**Edit: Sorry, forgot an explanation :) I would like to create some sort of notification popup window like outlook does to notify user of something. While opacity works well, animating or setting height to 0 does not.**

Comment: Why would you need this?

Comment: What do you want that for?

Comment: Oh sorry, edited for explanation.

Comment: @Samuel If you need a popup, use a `Popup`, not a `Window`.

Comment: While Popup sounds totally reasonable and I will take a look at it I am still curious what constraint prohibits the height of 0 (it is not MinHeight)

Comment: As PresentationCore seems to be undebuggble for me as presentationcore.pdb does not contain source information I am unable to debug it.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon

Comment: If you want an animation, think about animating the margin, not the height. So if you want your notification window to slide in, just start at a margin of -50 or something. Perhaps you can show some of your animation code, this would it make easier to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I spent a little research. First, this code:

```
<Window x:Class="ZeroHwindow.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="0" Width="525" 
    WindowStyle="None" 
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    Background="Yellow" />
```

Returns the value of the height of `6`, because you have `14`. I run this code on `Windows XP`, I suspect that you have a different OS. Next I set the parameter `ResizeMode` in `NoResize`, and got the height 2.

If you set `ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"`, we get as much as 17 pixels, which would fit the `Grip`. We see therefore that the system itself inserts standard elements, even when the parameters are: `WindowStyle="None", AllowsTransparency="True"`.

I also tried to set the parameters: `ShowInTaskbar = False`, `ShowActivated = False`, no avail, the window was not visible, but the height was 2 (it turns out that some people believe nothing to these parameters, in fact, height / width is not zero).

By the way, I forgot to mention: I showed all the values in the

```
ContentRendered="Window_ContentRendered"
```

like that:

```
private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(this.Height.ToString()); 
    MessageBox.Show(this.ActualHeight.ToString());
}
```

Just trying to set the `SizeToContent = WidthAndHeight`: the same height - 2, but the `Window` is not visible.

The only thing that somehow helped, it:

```
private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
    this.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0));

    MessageBox.Show(this.Height.ToString()); 
    MessageBox.Show(this.ActualHeight.ToString());
}
```

In thic case, ActualHeight return `0`.

Perhaps a standard element is drawn, and it is impossible to get `0`. I also tried to set `Styles / Templates`, but the height was not set to zero. In principle, as expected, for sure it is set at the system level.

Still decided to look at it through the `Snoop`.

**`Part #1. Standard state`**

[image]

You can see that the local value is set high.

**`Part #2. Using Arrange and Measure`**

[image]

Some links:

[UIElement.Arrange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.arrange.aspx)

[UIElement.Measure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.measure.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Since you have no borders, just [`Hide`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.hide.aspx) and [`Show`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.show.aspx) the window instead of setting it's `Height` to zero or a positive value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I extended my question to explain my motivation.

Comment: It is intended to be animated. Finally a Hide will be called as well but I wanted to achieve some shrink effect.